# How to make communication between one server and multiple client in Java Socket Programming?

Tags: java, sockets, client-server, serversocket

I have two java applications, one is web app and another is simple java app, So I am using Socket programming for communication between them.

I made one SocketServer which is a Thread, in which I created `ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(6789)`
And in my web app I created `Socket client = new Socket("localhost", 6789);`
My server  sends some data to client and client will start some other work, but if I want to run another client i.e. server will send different parameters and client have to start processing what should I do?

Because server is already started on '6789' port and first client also with the same port. How can I start client with another port?

Every time Server must have to started first and then client.

I think client will not found server till both are having same ports.

Am I have to create another server instance with different port and then invoke client??? But How can my client will know on which port server is started?

For Example:

Imagine I have UI like:

start  MIlind

start  xyz

start  abc

and click on strart it will call client and start process, If an start Milind first then How will I start xyz?
because 'start Milind' started client and server at port 6789, How will other start process works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like a lot of overhead to create a server/client app just for a web app to communicate with a local java program (and even more so to duplicate this process to do more than one thing at a time).  If you are looking for concurrent processing in the background of a web app, you can always just create a thread (or multiple threads) to do the work.  Or is there a reason why the simple java app can't be embedded in the web app?

Comment: yes...my java app is doing only the background processes, I cant change it to web app its like a library.
And If I made different threads then how can my client will know about the new port?

Comment: You don't have to change it to a web app, you can just use it in your web app like any other library.  I'm not sure what you mean by client knowing about the new port though.  Are you planning on sending an update to the client once the processing has been completed?

Comment: please see my updated question..If u cant understand please let me know.

Comment: If you are using threads you don't have to worry about ports, you just spawn new threads as you need them.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean... are you trying to update the client when the thread is done processing?

Comment: yes...My server is thread and client is just a class which accepts params sent by server and will start process.

Comment: For my solution, there is no more server, and the "clients" are just new threads you spawn and pass them the parameters to start the work in the background.  I would read up more on threading as you're going to need it for either solution: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17550/discussion-between-milind-ensarm-and-jordan-denison)

Answer (score 2):

You need to split off threads when accepting your socket connections server side. This is very easily done with serversocket. A very rudimentary (untested!) implementation:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

class Server {

    private ServerSocket socket;

    public Server() {
        try {
            this.socket = new ServerSocket(6789);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void go() throws IOException {
        while(true) {
            Socket sock = socket.accept();
            new Thread(new ClientSession(sock)).start();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Server server = new Server();
        try {
            server.go();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    class ClientSession implements Runnable {

        private final Socket clientsocket;

        ClientSession(Socket sock) {
            this.clientsocket = sock;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            //do stuff, like read from socket.
        }

    }

}
```

Note that you don't need to change the port at all.

Comment: can you please give me example?? I do not have clear idea about Sockets.. :(